# Limit usb power output

Tags: embedded, usb

I work with an embedded device that has a USB host port. I would like to connect an iPhone to it and communicate via USB. I have done development on this and ported the functionality to connect to usbmux on the iPhone and have successful communication, however there is another problem.

All development was done with the iPhone connected to a powered USB hub that was connected to my device, as soon as I connected it directly, after enumeration it starts to drain the battery of my embedded device and causes a tension (voltage) drop that causes my device to turn off.

I know that after enumeration usb devices can draw up to 500 mA from the usb port, but I was wondering if there was a way to limit that to 100 mA (while still having the iPhone registered).

I found various questions regarding controlling voltage on the data pins or vcc from the usb port and I understand that's not possible, I'm looking for a software solution (although hardware solutions are welcome).

tl;dr: Is there a way to supply the iPhone with less than 500 mA after enumeration? Could I do this in software? Or do I need a hardware solution? I don't want to turn the port on/off, just limit the power draw of the iPhone.

NOTE: I am using Windows CE 6.0, if it is something that can only be done by modifying the drivers, or having direct access, there is no problem.

P.S. also, if there is a way to do this in *nix (or some other open source OS) that I could look at the source code and port it to Windows CE please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

When a device shares its available configurations (see USB chapter 9), it specifies how much power it requires for each configuration.  The host should look at all the available configurations and choose which one it wants.

In practice, however, these things don't work so smoothly.

The last time I looked at this, Windows always chose the first configuration.  MacOS always chose the lowest power configuration (or highest, I can't remember).  I never looked at WinCE or Linux.

If you're writing/modifying the driver, you can set your own rules for which configuration to choose, including looking for one that's 'self powered'.   The iPhone, however, might only have one descriptor that always requests 500mA, bus powered.  If so, then you're pretty much screwed since there's no way to let the iPhone know it's not OK to draw power.

That being said, I believe all the iPhone accessories are actually USB host (as opposed to USB device), and given that they don't always supply power, the iPhone must be capable of enumerating self powered.

Comment: The iPhone has 4 different configurations actually, all are self-powered (bmAttributes = 0xc0), but http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml says that " If a device uses any power from the bus... it must report its power consumption in bMaxPower.", which it does, and I have to use a specific configuration that allows usb communication with apps. So I can't choose a different configuration, but I had heard that you can change the mA delivered to devices in Windows 7 in Device Manager, under Power Management on a usb hub, although I can't seem to find that option.

Comment: There are lots of devices on (e.g.) Amazon which lets you *measure* how much current is being drawn, but none let you dial in the maximum they will let pass? This would be so useful for cases where you want to maintain a given battery level on the charger while the device is active.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by Russ Schultz but I want to add another one:
No.

The descriptor of the peripheral device, iPhone in this case contains bMaxPower. If you enumerate this device, you also accept the power demand. It is not possible to only supply less, lets say 300 mA, if you already enumerated the device with the 500 mA desriptor. If this is what you wanted.

If the device provides multiple configurations, you are as mentioned by Russ free to write a driver which selects the configuration with less power. Hopefully, the device will then only consume the granted power.

Many peripheral devices just don't care. Most devices only provide one configuration with 500 mA. And there are a lot of devices which just consume more than they say ...

Comment: so there's not, say, some way to adjust how much current you are supplying a device (say a phone) so that you maintain a constant (non-full) battery charge level while the device is active?